# Maven version error during build

Tags: maven, tycho

I get the following error when I am trying to build my project

> Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.25.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) on project com.google.guice: Maven version 8.0.0.qualifier must have -SNAPSHOT qualifier for SNAPSHOT builds -> [Help 1]

I am not using release plugin for my build. I haven't seen this error before and not very certain about its meaning. All I am doing is changing version from in my pom from "-SNAPSHOT" to ".qualifier". Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? As far as I can tell I am not doing anything different from previous times I've build release version of my projects.

Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>com.google.guice</artifactId>
<!-- BEFORE -->
<version>8.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!-- NOW -->
<version>8.0.0.qualifier</version>
<build>
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Why not changing back to the state before as the error message says ?

Comment: I could do it, but I want to have a desired versioning - 8.0.0.R.2017123 for example.

Comment: Which is not a valid OSGi version...which prevents that.

Comment: Do you mean that '.' after 'R'? You can omit that - 8.0.0.R2017123. This is a valid version.